# Quick 2's Complement Subtraction/Addition in hexadecimal

Tags: binary, hex, computer-science

i made a long post but I'll keep it simpler.

Can someone show me a step by step for -10+-10 in hexadecimal for signed 16-bits?

the hexadecimal numbers would look like 0xFFF6+0xFFF6

I've heard it should equal 0xFFEC which should be -20. Anyone? Pretty please?

Answer (score 0):

**Addition**

When adding the two numbers, use the usual method of adding the digits by place value.

```
   0xFFF6  (-10)           0xFFF  6    (6)
 + 0xFFF6  (-10)    >>   - 0xFFF  6    (6)
-----------------       ------------ ------
                                  C   (12)
```

Carry when needed.

```
                                                   1  <-- Carried
   0x F F  F 6   (15)                         0x F F F 6
 - 0x F F  F 6   (15)           >>          - 0x F F F 6
--------------- ------                     --------------
          1E C   (30)                                E C
          ^        +-- need to carry 16
          |
Carry this to next place value
```

Continue until all digits are accounted for. Discard overflow carry. Overflow is checked using sign.

```
         1                   1 1
    0x F F F 6            0x F F F 6            0xFFF6  (-10)
  - 0x F F F 6    >>    - 0x F F F 6    >>    - 0xFFF6  (-10)
 --------------        --------------        -----------------
        1F E C              1F F E C            0xFFEC  (-20)
                            ^
                            |
                         Discard
```

**Subtraction**

Adding a negative is the same as subtracting the positive. Turn `-10 + -10` into `-10 - 10` by taking the 2's complement of the subtrahend.

```
   0xFFF6  (-10)                            0xFFF6  (-10)
 + 0xFFF6  (-10)   >> 2's complement >>   - 0x000A  (+10)
-----------------                        -----------------
```

Next, use binary subtraction and borrow as needed.

```
     Borrow                        Borrowed
       |                              |
       v                              v
   0xFFF  6   (  6)            0xFFE  16   ( 22)
 - 0x000  A   (-10)    >>    - 0x000   A   (-10)
------------ -------        ------------- -------
```

Continue until all digits are accounted for.

```
    0xFFE  16   ( 22)            0xFFE  16            0xFFF6
  - 0x000   A   (-10)    >>    - 0x000   A    >>    - 0x000A
 ------------- -------        -------------        ----------
            C   ( 12)            0xFFE   C            0xFFEC
```

**Overflow**

Once finished, check for overflow. The sign will be incorrect if overflow occurred (subtracting from a negative has to be negative).

```
0xFFEC  ->  negative (no overflow)
```